# Get row data inside function when embedding a data-table component

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a in house designed Data-Table that is being used by all developers at my workspace. Changing it for a minor task is not feasible for me, Hence I opted to figure out something else.

The data-table is given a list of columns `tableHeads`, list of rows `data` and a list of hover buttons `buttons: ['viewDetail', 'editButton', 'processButton']`. Now I need to hide one of the button if any row has status `in-progress` on hover.

I have tried to bind `hoverButtons` property with a `setHoverBittons()` that return list of buttons, But I am unable to get hovered row inside function so can I apply condition to remove `editButton` button from the list of "buttons"

My `data-table` component can be embed in my `component.html` like

```
<data-table ngIf="dataLoaded" [hoverButtons]="buttons" [tableHeads]="tableHeads" [data]="data"></data-table>
```

Whereas in my `component.ts`, I have

```
tableHeads = [{ 'fieldName': '...', 'labelName': '...', 'checked': true },
{ 'fieldName': '....', 'labelName': '...', 'checked': true },
{ 'fieldName': '...', 'labelName': '...', 'checked': true },
{ 'fieldName': 'status', 'labelName': 'Status', 'checked': true }];

buttons = ["viewDetail", "editButton", "processButton"];

data = [{ ..., status: 'in-progress' }, { ..., status: 'completed' }, ...];
```

Now I tried to bind a function to `[hoverButtons]` in html like

```
<data-table ngIf="dataLoaded" [hoverButtons]="setHoverButtons(row)" [tableHeads]="tableHeads" [data]="data"></data-table>
```

Whereas in my `ts` file

```
setHoverButtons(row) {
    console.log(row); // row is undefined - this is the main problem
    // if row.status === 'in-progress'
    // // return ["viewDetail", "processButton"] 
    // else 
    return ["viewDetail", "editButton", "processButton"];
}
```

I just want to have 2 buttons instead of all 3 on hover. If the status is `in-progress`. Rest will remain same.

Comment: from where are you calling `setHoverButtons` method?

Comment: <data-table ngIf="dataLoaded" [hoverButtons]="setHoverButtons(row)" [tableHeads]="tableHeads" [data]="data"></data-table>

Comment: I think maybe the setHoverButtons should be called from your data-table, not the component.ts file.

Comment: it is better to first call the `setHoverButtons` method from another method like `ngOnInit`. Because `hoverButtons` is an input parameter to the component, it takes values, if you are not calling `setHoverButtons` method then `hoverButtons` will not get any values.

Comment: setHoverButtons will be called on hover, so no need to call it onInit

Comment: could you try emitting an event on hover, which will invoke the method.

Comment: yeah, that is an option. But what if I cannot change/emit from the data-table?

Comment: then it will be difficult for the outer component to know which data to pass.

Answer (score 0):

To me, it looks like you pass the buttons to be displayed from your component.ts to the the data-table.

If that is the case, you could change the buttons array depending on the status `in-progress`, which also seems to come from your component.ts file. If that is the case, I would do something like this:

in component.ts

```
allButtons ["viewDetail", "editButton", "processButton"];
fewerButtons ["viewDetail", "editButton"];
buttons = [...allButtons];
data = [{ ..., status: 'in-progress' }, { ..., status: 'completed' }, ...];

functionForHandlingTheDataArray(){
  // if data[i].status === 'in-progress' then 
  this.buttons = [...this.fewerButtons];
}
```

I have noe idea if this is what you want, but this is how I interpret your question

Comment: // if data[i].status === 'in-progress' then
How will I get `i` inside the function on hover?

Comment: I think maybe I misunderstood the question, because I now think that the data is being processed inside `data-table`. You should do the logic there instead.